# get time from computer system in php

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get time from computer system in php and I want it exactly as in computer , not other format.

I have already did it in javascript but it client side and I want server side.
So I am trying it in php.

Is it possible in php?

Comment: You mean from the client's computer? That's not possible on server side.

Comment: What does "I want it exactly as in computer , not other format." mean?

Comment: PHP is server side, JS is client side. You can't get client side information server side. If you already have it in JS just pass that value to the PHP to get it server side

Comment: @Quentin : same time format in computer

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' — What format is that?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the date/time of the server (the machine that runs PHP), you can use the `date` function.

Directly from [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
?>
```

If you mean from the client's computer, then it couldn't be done. PHP is server-side.

Answer (score 1):

> from client's computer.

Browsers do not send the current time with every request, so PHP running on the server has no way of knowing what the client clock is set to (unless you use JavaScript (or some other technology you can use client side) to collect the time and make an HTTP request to the server that includes it explicitly).

Comment: You can still check the request headers such as `Accept-Language` and "guess" the date/time format used on the client.

Comment: @SalmanA — The relationship between time zone and preferred language is far too weak to be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a language that is executed on the server side of things, code that is never seen by the CLIENT's computer. The problem that you are trying to solve can not be done with PHP. To get the date/time of the server running the PHP, see the following:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php